# How to find duplicate in an array with using a single array

Tags: arrays

I came across a code which is able to find the duplicate in the array using tht same particular array, but however it doesnot work well when the default array contains negative value

```
void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
      int i;  

      printf("\n The repeating elements are");

      for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        if(arr[abs(arr[i])] > 0)
          arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];
        else
          printf(" %d ", abs(arr[i]));
      }         
    }     

    int main()
    {
      int arr[] = {1, 3, 2, 2, 1};
      int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
      printRepeating(arr, arr_size);
      getchar();
      return 0;
    }
```

This is the code I found which works fine for positive values but not for negative values.any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how is this working fine. Look at the code. You have a printRepeating function, which expects an array, representing the set of elements and an integer, representing the size of the set of elements. So far, so good

In this function you are using the element values as indexes. That's not how things should be done. If those elements are negative, then they are out of bounds. This is what you correctly observed. Also, if those elements are greater or equal than size, then you attempt to use elements outside the array. This is the syntactic level of the problem.

Let's see the semantics. Let us suppose that we will have no out of bounds problem even with big positive numbers or negatives. Let us focus at the idea of the algorithm. It negates the sign of the given index and at the next occurrence negates again. It is not elegant to change the values of an array when that is not the purpose. There are situations, when changing element values is not an option, so you should only change them when that is what you intend. Let's see whether you like this one:

```
void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
      int i;
      int j;

      printf("\n The repeating elements are");

      for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
          if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
              //handle the duplicate
              j = size;
          }
        }
      }         
}
```

EDIT:

Based on the newly described needs, you need two functions:
- `isDuplicate`
- `insertElement`

```
int isDuplicate(int arr[], int size, int newElement) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == newElement) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int insertElement(int arr[], int size, int newElement) {
    int dupe = isDuplicate(arr, size, newElement);
    if (dupe == false) {
        arr[size] = newElement;
    }
    return dupe;
}
```

Comment: well that particular code i was able to execute on my own..anyways thank you for the info(insights u provided on the error that i'd be facing)

Comment: It is good that you have achieved that on your own. However, my answer aimed to explain you the problems you are facing and to suggest an alternative. You might consider accepting this as an answer.

Comment: but what i wan try to do is while inserting element into an array itself i want to check for duplicacy...can u help with tht?

Comment: So you want to check whether the element is already present in the array and if so, insert it?

Comment: I have tried this particular code and  achieved what i wanted to do,,,but i am trying to optimize the code hence i would want to try to find duplicacy without using loops

Comment: You will not achieve that without loops.

Comment: can we do something like storing a particular elements on the index position which is same as the user entered element ,hence when next same element is entered we check for a existence?

Comment: Not really. You would need to allocate an infinitely big part of the memory just to support natural numbers, which is impossible by itself. You will not be able to do it with negative integers, nor with other types, such as floats or strings. Your idea for optimization is unrealistic in this case.

Comment: oh ok u gto some valid points there...thank you for the insights